# Determining the number of distinct subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gcd-and-lcm

Given x, an element of order 627 in a group G (not necessarily cyclic, finite, or Abelian). How many distinct subgroups of G are contained in $\langle x \rangle$?

I'm not sure if I'm reasoning this out correctly. So since $|x| = 627$, there should be $627$ subgroups of x. To determine distinct subgroups, we can use a theorem.

**Thm:** Let $|a| = n$, let $k$ be a positive integer. Then $|a^k| = \frac{n}{gcd(n,k)}$ and $\langle a^k \rangle = \langle a^{gcd(n,k)} \rangle$.

As well as the corollary that says $\langle a \rangle = \langle a^j \rangle$ if and only if $gcd(n,j)$ = 1 where $|a| = n$.

So one way that seems obvious is to go through $k \in [0,627]$ and slowly determine each distinct subgroup. But is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: What is the prime factorisation of $627$?

Comment: 3*11*19. 8 divisors.

Comment: Good, then how many subgroups does a cyclic group of order $627$ have? Is it (a) $627$, (b) $8$, (c) something else?

Comment: If it's cyclic, then I believe it would be 8. But the question specifies that it isn't necessarily cyclic, finite or Abelian.

Comment: While the group $G$ is not cyclic the subgroup $\langle x \rangle$ is by definition and it is the only group whose properties are required to solve this problem.

Comment: In fact the information that $G$ is not necessarily finite, cyclic, abelian, nilpotent, solvable, free, Hopfian, or residually finite is completely irrelevant and has been put in deliberately to distract you. Very cruel!